# Stützen, abstützen, aufstützen

Tags: meaning, difference

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen stützen, abstützen, aufstützen? Und mit welchen Präpositionen werden sie benutzt?

Comment: Du stellst hier zwei verschiedene Fragen. Eine in der Überschrift, und eine ganz andere im Fließtext. Bitte stelle nur eine Frage pro Posting. Falls aus deiner Sicht ein Zusammenhang zwischen deinen beiden Fragen bestehen sollte (wenn es also nur zwei Aspekte derselben Frage sind), wäre es hilfreich, wenn du diesen Zusammenhang thematisieren würdest.

Comment: Welcome to this site! Would you please edit your question and add, what exactly is not clear to you after looking up those words in a dictionary?

Comment: Übersetzung ist ungefähr gleich - to prop, ich arbeite in der Pflege und mir ist es nicht klar, was ist der Unterschied und in welcher Situationen werden diese Verben benutzt

Answer (score 1):

These three words are very similar. The only difference that comes to my mind being "stützen" is used when you actively support someone (Ich stütze meinen verletzten Mitspieler/I prop my injured teammate), whereas "abstützen" is used by the supported one, who leans onto something/someone (Ich stütze mich auf meinem Mitspieler ab/I am leaning on my teammate).

"Aufstützen" ist sometimes being used as a synonym for "stützen", although native speakers mostly do not bother to attach the "auf-". It is being used however as a description for a foul in sports like soccer, when either attacker or defender jump onto their opponent, holding him down with their arms and thus preventing him from jumping, which we then call "Aufstützen".

Comment: Ob man etwas stützt oder abstützt, etwa ein Gebäude mit einem Pfeiler - hat nichts mit der Perspektive zu tun. Ich stütze mich da nicht auf den Duden. Die andere Bedeutung wird in Deinem Fall von dem reflexiven "mich" verursacht, nicht von abstützen. Ebenso sind die Verben agnostisch darüber, ob ich mich oder sie sich stützt/abstützt. Und jetzt stütze ich wieder meinen Kopf mit dem Arm auf dem Knie ab, um einer Figur Rodins ähnlich zu sehen.